# What are SPOIDCRL cookie and IDCRL (Identity Client Runtime library)?

Tags: authentication, cookie

I have been working with FedAuth cookie and sometimes rtFA cookie with Office365 authentication.  Recently I came across SPOIDCRL cookie while logging in using .NET library, but I couldn't find much information on that, or the related library IDCRL.  Questions:

- What is the IDCRL libraray, when and how is it used?  How does it fit into the big picture of authentication generally?  (so far all I got from my search is that it appears to be used heavily by various Online apps)
- What is SPOIDCRL or other IDCRL cookie?  How is it related to the other common claim based cookies (FedAuth)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my understanding is that not much has changed. SharePoint Online is now looking for SPOIDCRL cookie rather than FedAuth cookie. The FedAuth cookie was used and depended a lot on ADFS. The new SPOIDCRL is now using Azure AD Sync Service.