# SPOIDCRL cookie authentication stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-online

I used a flow described in many places of the Internet, obtaining the SPOIDCRL cookie and using it in Python scripts to work with the SharePoint 365 resources.

Recently, that stopped working. I started getting the `401 Unauthorized` error at the last step:

`GET https://<TenantURL>/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/`

with this message in the Response Headers:

`X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.`

Could you please suggest what was changed on the SharePoint side to stop this authentication method working?

And what alternative method could be used in this situation?

Comment: Did you already did that, `+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.`?

Comment: Yesterday I was able to verify this authentication method in other tenants using a PowerShell script. And it still worked. So It could be that the token issued by the company's ADFS is not accepted by SharePoint's idcrl.svc. Unfortunately, I don't know a way to tell why exactly the token is rejected.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey, the message is quite cryptic, it is hard to follow it as it is now. I have looked around and saw some ways to implement a different authentication flow. My main question there is what prevents SharePoint to generate the SPOIDCRL cookie as it did before. If I knew that, I could request the SharePoint admins to roll that change back

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, For SPOIDCRL, SharePoint online is now using Azure AD Sync Service not ADFS. Hope this help, [For more details](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132122/what-are-spoidcrl-cookie-and-idcrl-identity-client-runtime-library)

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, or start with python graph SharePoint online, a new way of authentication [Get started with Microsoft Graph and Python](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/python)

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, after disabling the legacy authentication on my tenants, I was able to replicate this issue several days later. Today, I am getting the same error. Not sure why. It might be either due to some changes in SharePoint online, or the legacy authentication takes a few days to disable. Either way, I now suspect the disabled legacy authentication is indeed the issue here.